# Activity is not updated from the Live Data

Tags: android, mvvm, geolocation, viewmodel, android-location

I am trying to build a weather app so i am using the mvvm artitecture and i am using location services to get the current location, I am fetching the location in viewModel,But it's not getting updated on the screen , when i have used the location services directly on the mainacticity it is showing the results but once i defined the same function in another class, the ui gets not updated.

**Below is the code**

MainActicity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var weatherModel:WeatherViewModel
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
//    private var latitude:Double = 00.00
//    private var longitude:Double = 00.00



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        weatherModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[WeatherViewModel::class.java]
//        Log.d("weatherModel","${weatherModel.weatherResp}")
//        Log.d("longi","$longitude")
//        weatherModel.getWeather(latitude,longitude)

        //accessing location from viewModel
        if(weatherModel.fetchLocation()){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),101)
            return
        }
        weatherModel.weatherResp.observe(this){
            weather->
            binding.apply {
                tvDescription.text = weather.weather[0].description
                livelocation.setOnClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "this is rohit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                tvWind.text = weather.wind.speed.toString() + " Km/h"
                humidity.text = weather.main.humidity.toString()
                val tempInC = weather.main.temp - 273.15
                val number3digits:Double = (tempInC * 1000.0).roundToInt() / 1000.0
                tvTemperature.text = number3digits.toString()
                visibility.text = weather.visibility.toString()
//


            }

        }


    }
//    private fun fetchLocation(){
//        val task = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
//        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
//        !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
//           ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
//           !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
//                ){
//            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),101)
//            return
//        }
//        task.addOnSuccessListener {
//            if(it!=null){
//                latitude=it.latitude
//                longitude= it.longitude
//                weatherModel.getWeather(latitude,longitude)
//                Log.d("longi","$longitude")
//                val address = getAddressName(it.latitude,it.longitude)
//                binding.tvCityName.text = address
//            }
//        }
//
//    }
//    private fun getAddressName(lat:Double,long:Double):String{
//        Log.d("lat", lat.toString())
//        var addressName = " "
//        val geoCoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
//        val address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat,long,1)
//        if (address != null) {
//            addressName = address[0].subAdminArea
//        }
//        Log.d("Address", address.toString())
//        Log.d("subadmin",addressName.toString())
//        return addressName
//
//    }
//
//
//    private fun getCoordinates(cord:String){
//        var city = binding.locationQuery.text.toString()
////        val geocodeListener = Geocoder.GeocodeListener { addresses ->
////            addresses[0]
////        }
//        val geocoder = Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault())
//        val address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(city,2)
//        val result = address?.get(0)
//
//
//    }
}
```

WeatherViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class WeatherViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo:WeatherRepository,
    private val application: Application,
    private val fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
) :ViewModel(){
    private var getLatitude: Double = 00.00
    private var getLongitude: Double = 00.00

    private val _resp = MutableLiveData<WeatherDTO>()
    val weatherResp:LiveData<WeatherDTO>
    get() = _resp



    private val _cord = MutableLiveData<Coord>()
    val cord:LiveData<Coord>
        get() = _cord


//    init {
//        check()
//        getWeather(getLatitude,getLongitude)
//    }

   fun getWeather(latitude:Double,longitude:Double) =
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repo.getWeather(latitude,longitude).let { response->

                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    _resp.postValue(response.body())
                }else{
                    Log.d("Weather Error","getWeather Error Response: ${response.message()}")
                }
            }
        }


    fun fetchLocation():Boolean{
        val task = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(application,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(application,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ){
            return true
        }
        task.addOnSuccessListener {
            if(it!=null){
//                latitude=it.latitude
//                longitude= it.longitude
                getWeather(it.latitude,it.longitude)
//                Log.d("lati","${it.latitude}")
//                Log.d("longimaa","${it.longitude}")
//                val address = getAddressName(it.latitude,it.longitude)
//                _cord.postValue(it.latitude,it.longitude)
//                binding.tvCityName.text = address
            }
        }
        return true

    }

    private fun fetchLocationDetails(){

    }
    private fun getAddressName(lat:Double,long:Double):String{
        Log.d("lat", lat.toString())
        var addressName = " "
        val geoCoder = Geocoder(application, Locale.getDefault())
        val address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat,long,1)
        if (address != null) {
            addressName = address[0].subAdminArea
        }
        Log.d("Address", address.toString())
        Log.d("subadmin",addressName.toString())
        return addressName

    }






}
```

Comment: Can you make sure if you are getting inside repo.getWeather(latitude,longitude).let and then inside if(response.isSuccessful){

Comment: @theanilpaudel Yes, I am getting the response like this
WeatherDTO(base=stations, clouds=Clouds(all=40), cod=200, coord=Coord... along with coordinates

Answer (score 0):

I am trying and the screen results gets updated

```
binding.livelocation.setOnClickListener {
        if(weatherModel.fetchLocation()){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),101)
        }
    }
```

But still didn't know how this is working and when put outside of this button listener it is not

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).